# Java won't let me allocate more ram for my minecraft server on my rP4 8 GB

Tags: pi-4, linux, minecraft

I recently setup a minecraft server on my raspberry pi 4 8GB running ubuntu server version 20.04, everything on the server works fine, but when I try to allocate 4 gigabytes of ram to the server with the command:java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar minecraft_server.1.17.jar nogui. I get the error that this number exceeds the maximum heap size even though, when I give the free command it says I have over 6 GB of free memory. I'm running java 16 but I'm not sure if it is 32 or 64 bit since I used apt install to install it. When I do `java -version` I get `openjdk version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-1) OpenJDK Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-1, mixed mode)` The maximum it lets me allocate now is 2 GB so I was wondering if there was anyway to fix the issue.

Comment: are you running a 64bit operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working with an installer for Java 17 following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT-siImC0tM